# How to restrict checkbox selection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 10 check boxes in a screen. I want check only 5 check boxes. If I check more than 5 checkboxes, I need to show one alert message, "select only 5 check box".

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syv8cww1/75/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    
    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'item1',
        selected: true
    },{
        id: 2,
        title: 'item2',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 3,
        title: 'item3',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 4,
        title: 'item4',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 5,
        title: 'item5',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 6,
        title: 'item6',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 7,
        title: 'item7',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 8,
        title: 'item8',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 9,
        title: 'item9',
        selected: false
    },{
        id: 10,
        title: 'item10',
        selected: false
    }
    ];
    
    
              
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input id="{{ item.id }}"
               type="checkbox"
               ng-model="item.selected"
               ng-checked="item.selected" />
    <label for="{{ item.id }}" >{{ item.title }}</label>
</div>
</div>
```

On click of checkbox itself I need to show the alert message. I need to select only 5 checkbok at a time. Not more than 5. Please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the selected checkboxes in a foreach onclick and show alert if count >5

```
$scope.checkSelected = function(item){
    var c = 0;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
     if(item.selected){
      c++;  
     }   
    });
    if(c>5){
     item.selected = false;
     alert('Not more than 5');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add watcher that will validate checkbox list for selected count:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.items;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue !== undefined && oldValue !== undefined){
  var selected =  newValue.filter(function(_item){
             return _item.selected == true;
      });

      if(selected.length > 4){
       //disable other checkboxes
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, key) {
           if(item.selected === false){
           item.disabled = true;
           }
        });
      }
      else{ // enable all
         angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, key) {
           item.disabled = false;
        });
      }
    }        
}, true);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aysycekd/)</kbd>

Comment: This is working. But it is just showing alert message. If more than 5 I need to show alert message and Need to uncheck the remaining selected.

Comment: Hey sorry not like this. Don't disable remaining fields. I jst want to show alert message and uncheck the remaining.

Comment: @sathishkumar I think you can do your homework to accomplish this task :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving them classes then using js to select the class and do a count of how many have selected:true

```
if($('#myclass option:selected').length() > 4){
    alert("WARNING")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ng-change` directive.

```
<input id="{{ item.id }}"
           type="checkbox"
           ng-model="item.selected"
           ng-change="processChecked(item)" />

$scope.processChecked = function(item) {
    var checked = $scope.items.filter(function(i) {
      return i.selected;
    });

    if (checked.length > 5) {
      alert("more than 5!");
      item.selected = false; // undo last action
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This is fine. But I want to uncheck the remaining selected item(6th one).

Comment: @sathishkumar if the "undo last action" didn't get triggered, you might need to wrap it in a `$timeout`. `$timeout(function() { item.selected = false; });`